# Tiny MCE WYSIWYG editor control which <textarea> it applies to

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

We have limited but necessary text edit requirements and are using the free version of TinyMCE 6 on a web page which has more than one instance of the textarea tag.

Not all textareas should be initialized by TicyMCE editor.

The textareas that need to be initialized have ids similar to 'mailmatter_1','mailmatter_2', 'mailmatter_3', ....

The number of such textarea fields are not fixed, they change as per requirement.

What we are trying to figure out is when initializing TinyMCE how to use wildcards
The following does not work

```
    tinyMCE.init({
selector: 'textarea#[id^="mailmatter_"]',
    });
```

A similar setup with another editor (Summernote), we could use

```
$('[id^=mailmatter_]').summernote({
```

How might we restrict TinyMCE to known textarea's but not all textareas
thank you for your help

Comment: What happens when you do use the first selector you show here? Are any of the textareas initialized for tinyMCE? Can you list them individually, such as `textarea#target1,textarea#target2`? Can you include the relevant html?

Comment: Have you tried the alternative [editor_selector](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@editor_selector/) which you set a css class to initialize tinyMCE and not by id's?

Comment: Does the selector you used work otherwise in javascript or CSS?

Comment: yes - the editor is there and useable.  Like the idea of using CSS to initialise tinyMCE and will test this asap  thank you

Comment: at the moment we cannot get the css initialisation to work 
so have tried textarea#target1,textarea#target2 which works. But not ideal solution, as the number of textareas are not predefined. A wild card would be the best solution

HTML
    <textarea name="target1" id="target1" placeholder='Intro in' style='width:90%;height:30px'></textarea>
    <textarea name="target2" id="target2" placeholder='Intro in' style='width:90%;height:30px'></textarea>
    ......

JS
    tinyMCE.init({
      selector: "textarea#target1'",
    });

Comment: thank you @mykaf 
in the end this works really well
so I have upvoted your comment ~ thank you